# trouble shoot a creating a mySQL function for parsing a string

Tags: mysql, create-function

I'm getting a SYNTAX error attempting to create a mySQL function to parse a string. It's probably something simple that I'm not realizing given that I have more experience creating FN's with SQL then MySQL.

Here's my function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_parse_string (string1 varchar(2048),datapoint1 varchar(20),delimiter1 

varchar(1)) 
RETURNS varchar(60) DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
    DECLARE datareturn1 VARCHAR(60)
    
    IF INSTR(string1, datapoint1) > 0 
        THEN 
            SET datareturn1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(string1,
                                                        INSTR(string1, datapoint1) + LENGTH(datapoint1),
                                                        LENGTH(string1)),
                                                delimiter1,
                                                1)
    ELSEIF IFNULL(datapoint1,'') = '' 
        THEN 
            SET datareturn1 = 'Blank Field'
    ELSE SET datareturn1 = 'N/A'
    END IF;


RETURN (datareturn1);
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that some semicolons missing, try it in this way please:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_parse_string (string1 varchar(2048),datapoint1 varchar(20),delimiter1 

varchar(1)) 
RETURNS varchar(60) DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
    DECLARE datareturn1 VARCHAR(60);
    
    IF INSTR(string1, datapoint1) > 0 
        THEN 
            SET datareturn1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(string1,
                                                        INSTR(string1, datapoint1) + LENGTH(datapoint1),
                                                        LENGTH(string1)),
                                                delimiter,
                                                1);
    ELSEIF IFNULL(datapoint1,'') = '' 
        THEN 
            SET datareturn1 = 'Blank Field';

    ELSE SET datareturn1 = 'N/A';
    END IF;


RETURN (datareturn1);
END
```

Comment: That worked thanks.  The intermediate semicolon throughout throws me a bit.  Much obliged!